# Недоступность robot.txt и manifest.json

Tags: веб-сервер

интересует такой вопрос, не так давно поставили ngix, и с момента его установки файлы robot.txt и manifest.json больше не доступны, при попытке доступа к ним выдается ошибка 403. Кто-то может подсказать, как с этим бороться?

Comment: Добавьте конфиг. Иначе это будет просто гадание

Comment: И заодно в каком каталоге лежат указанные файлы

Comment: Прошу прощения за долгий ответ, а откуда можно его достать?

Comment: поставили nginx, значит где-то лежит его файл nginx.conf,